# VIN Number Validation Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 for a current project. Project generally deals with Vehicles and identifying the correct vehicles for different usages.

I have the below model.

```
public class Vehicle
{
   [Required]
   public string VIN{get; set;}
   //
}
```

I want to verify the correct incoming VIN number. I am not sure what is the correct/easiest way to validate something like a VIN number. I have seen some validation examples, none seemed to work for me. Need some help on Client side validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using RegularExpression for validating VIN in my own project. Try the below example:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [RegularExpression("[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{13}[0-9]{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Vehicle Identification Number Format.")]
    public string VIN { get; set; }
}
```

VIN usually consist of 17 characters.

The very first letter or number of the VIN tells you in what region of the world your vehicle was made.

The second letter or number, in combination with the first letter or number in the VIN, tells you in what country the car or truck was made.

The third number or letter is used by the vehicle manfacturer to identify what kind of vehicle it is.

The 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th characters, you can find out the vehicle model, engine type, body style.

The 9th character is the VIN check digit where you can use math to figure out if it is a correct VIN.

The 10th letter or number of the VIN tells you the model year of the vehicle.

The 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th characters is where the auto manufacturers enter unique information about the particular vehicle the VIN belongs to.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

Here's @hardknocks answer in C#

```
public static bool ValidateVin(string vin)
{
    if (vin.Length != 17)
        return false;
    var result = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var checkDigit = 0;
    var checkSum = 0;
    var weight = 0;
    foreach (var c in vin.ToCharArray())
    {
        index++;
        var character = c.ToString().ToLower();
        if (char.IsNumber(c))
            result = int.Parse(character);
        else
        {
            switch (character)
            {
                case "a":
                case "j":
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                case "b":
                case "k":
                case "s":
                    result = 2;
                    break;
                case "c":
                case "l":
                case "t":
                    result = 3;
                    break;
                case "d":
                case "m":
                case "u":
                    result = 4;
                    break;
                case "e":
                case "n":
                case "v":
                    result = 5;
                    break;
                case "f":
                case "w":
                    result = 6;
                    break;
                case "g":
                case "p":
                case "x":
                    result = 7;
                    break;
                case "h":
                case "y":
                    result = 8;
                    break;
                case "r":
                case "z":
                    result = 9;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (index >= 1 && index <= 7 || index == 9)
            weight = 9 - index;
        else if (index == 8)
            weight = 10;
        else if (index >= 10 && index <= 17)
            weight = 19 - index;
        if (index == 9)
            checkDigit = character == "x" ? 10 : result;
        checkSum += (result * weight);
    }

    return checkSum % 11 == checkDigit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

VINs are validated using a check digit in the 9th place and formula you can pretty easily find.  Here's a VB version of the validation I wrote.  I'm a new VB programmer so there's more elegant ways I'm sure, but the logic is right...  "all one's" (see commented line) is a good check of any VIN validation algorithm.

```vbnet
Function ValidateVin(vin As String) As Boolean
        'Dim vin As String = "2G1FC3D33C9165616"
        'Dim vin As String = "11111111111111111"
        Dim vinCharArray() = vin.ToCharArray()
        Dim result As Int32
        Dim index As Int32 = 0
        Dim checkDigit As Int32
        Dim checkSum As Int32 = 0
        Dim weight As Int32

        If vin.Length <> 17 Then
            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + "Supplied VIN does not have 17 characters, please check and try again" + vbCrLf)
            Return False
        Else
            For Each i As Char In vinCharArray
                index += 1
                If Asc(i) > 47 And Asc(i) < 58 Then
                    result = Int32.Parse(i)
                Else
                    Select Case Char.ToLower(i)
                        Case "a", "j"
                            result = 1
                        Case "b", "k", "s"
                            result = 2
                        Case "c", "l", "t"
                            result = 3
                        Case "d", "m", "u"
                            result = 4
                        Case "e", "n", "v"
                            result = 5
                        Case "f", "w"
                            result = 6
                        Case "g", "p", "x"
                            result = 7
                        Case "h", "y"
                            result = 8
                        Case "r", "z"
                            result = 9
                    End Select
                End If
                Select Case index
                    Case 1 To 7, 9
                        weight = 9 - index
                    Case 8
                        weight = 10
                    Case 10 To 17
                        weight = 19 - index
                End Select
                If index = 9 Then
                    If Char.ToLower(i) = "x" Then
                        checkDigit = 10
                    Else
                        checkDigit = result
                    End If
                End If
                'Console.WriteLine("Index {0} has a value of {1} and a weight of {2}", index, result, weight)
                checkSum += (result * weight)
            Next

            'Console.WriteLine("checksum is {0}", checkSum)
            'Console.WriteLine("checkdigit is {0}", checkDigit)

            Dim checksOut As Boolean

            If checkSum Mod 11 = checkDigit Then
                checksOut = True
            End If

            'Console.WriteLine(checksOut)
            'Console.ReadLine()

            Return checksOut

        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can validate here:

1. Is the VIN provided correct. You can check that by calculating check digit and comparing it with the one from number. However, it will not work with all manufacturers. Check more on wikipedia: [Vehicle identification number: Check digit calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Check_digit_calculation).
2. Check if VIN matches other car details (make, model, etc.). To do that you'd have to have access to some database. I don't think you have one already, so you'd have to first look for one, then either use it's public API or copy data and write your own API and then use it to validate user data.

Comment: I tested that regex and it fails on some actual vin and on the one provided as example by Wikipedia (1HGBG41JXMN109186). I found this one that works much better for me: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2}[0-9]{6}` Of course, for the checksum (9th char) any letter or number is accepter there.

Comment: @Luca that new regex isn't a good VIN number check. For instance, that same page says that `I`, `O` and `Q` are not allowed, which you don't check for. Also, the regex in the top answer, `[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{13}[0-9]{4}`, _succeeds_ with your example string of `"1HGBG41JXMN109186"`.

Comment: @Abel, you are right. In my project I needed a simple way to tell apart strings that I know for sure are valid vins and strings that instead are test data with some random letters and numbers. Therefore for my case a check "it looks like a VIN" was good enough, even if far from perfect.